# Storyboard ContainerView doesn't pass it's bounds to contained UICollectionViewController.view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicontainerview

I made a container on the main `UIView` of my application to embed the `UICollectionViewController`. And this container is something like half of the window's height.

Then I try to calculate cell sizes for my `UICollectionView` to fit two columns and three rows. But the `UICollectionViewController` thinks it has all screen at it's disposal and calculates Cell height accordingly.

The embedded view controller is being instantiated before my Parent ViewController calls `-viewDidLoad` method.

How can i pass actual bounds of the Container to contained ViewController?

Comment: post code how you actually add child view controller and tell if autolayout is enabled?

Comment: How do things look once you get to `viewWillAppear` ?

Comment: @NikitaTook what do you mean by 'post code', i connect UICollectionViewController to my main UIViewController via Storyboard embed segue. Autolayout is enabled.

Comment: @MikePollard the embedded view controller thinks that it is fullscreen at that moment.

Comment: From my experience, autolayout tends to make these sort of difficulties. Check on the "onLoad" function the view's container frame width and height (should be the whole screen). Usually I go about this by removing the autolayout and making sure the anchor is just top-left , and no stretch vertically/horizontally is enabled.